# "Assignment outside section in config file." error when trying to run/autostart redshift

Tags: software-installation, configuration

I've made a config file as [instructed](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Redshift) at the bottom of the page,and i've made a file as follows.

```
; Global settings for redshift
[redshift]
; Set the day and night screen temperatures
temp-day=6700
temp-night=3500

; Enable/Disable a smooth transition between day and night
; 0 will cause a direct change from day to night screen temperature. 
; 1 will gradually increase or decrease the screen temperature
transition=1

; Set the screen brightness. Default is 1.0
;brightness=0.9
; It is also possible to use different settings for day and night since version 1.8.
;brightness-day=0.7
;brightness-night=0.4
; Set the screen gamma (for all colors, or each color channel  individually)
gamma=0.8
;gamma=0.8:0.7:0.8

; Set the location-provider: 'geoclue', 'gnome-clock', 'manual'
; type 'redshift -l list' to see possible values
; The location provider settings are in a different section.
location-provider=manual

; Set the adjustment-method: 'randr', 'vidmode'
; type 'redshift -m list' to see all possible values
; 'randr' is the preferred method, 'vidmode' is an older API
; but works in some cases when 'randr' does not.
; The adjustment method settings are in a different section.
adjustment-method=randr

; Configuration of the location-provider:
; type 'redshift -l PROVIDER:help' to see the settings
; e.g. 'redshift -l manual:help'
[manual]
lat=52.0
lon=1.4

; Configuration of the adjustment-method
; type 'redshift -m METHOD:help' to see the settings
; ex: 'redshift -m randr:help'
; In this example, randr is configured to adjust screen 1. 
; Note that the numbering starts from 0, so this is actually the   second screen.
[randr]
screen=1
```

When I run `gtk redshift`, i get: `Assignment outside section in config file. Unable to load config file.`

What do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saved it in mousepad instead, and set speech to =0 as I have 1 monitor. I have a graphical plasmoid for redshift set up which had different values to the config file (and could apply them), but i've changed them to be the same now.

I restarted the computer, and redshift is now on the taskbar and works.